# Retrieve tstamp in extbase

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I see that there's a 'last changed'-property in my table created with the extension builder called 'tstamp' but I can't figure out how to display it in the front-end.
In the front-end I'm using fluid like this, but it stays empty:

```
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y - H:i">{appointment.tstamp}</f:format.date>
```

I can see the property in the TCA also:

'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:extTest/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_extTest_domain_model_appointment',
        'label' => 'start_date',
        **'tstamp' => 'tstamp'**,

I tried adding this in my php class file but it didn't change anything

```
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $tstamp;

    /**
     * Get Tstamp
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getTstamp() {
        return $this->tstamp;
    }
```

I think the problem is that I don't understand the connection from the TCA to the PHP Class, can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you also need a TCA configuration for every field as extbase gets there required information (especially for relations). Therefore add something like this into the TCA of your table:

```
'tstamp' => [
  'label' => 'tstamp',
  'config' => [
   'type' => 'passthrough',
  ]
],
```

You don't need to add the field to a actual type.

The annotation in the model should be

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $tstamp;
```

So don't forget the `\`before the DateTime.

Clear caches and you are fine